# HTML - fontawesome replace icons

Tags: font-awesome

Im trying to replace the icon in html code, by using other fontawesome icon, but every time I post the new code but not working.

[image: those Icons I need to change]

[image: this the code I need to replace]

Comment: Are you including the script src in your header? That's using BoxIcons not FontAwesome. Please post your code here

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your kit's code to a project.

Copy your kit's code into the  of each template or page in your project where you want to use Font Awesome via this kit.

Example kit code :

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/12345abcdefg.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, afte checking again I find that the ICON in website was using icon with uncode, how I can remove it.